# Why does the value of typeof null change inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, v8

Executing this snippet in the Chrome console:

```js
function foo() {
    return typeof null === 'undefined';
}
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) console.log(foo());
```

should print 1000 times `false`, but on some machines will print `false` for a number of iterations, then `true` for the rest.

[image]

Why is this happening? Is it just a bug?

Comment: It is returning 1000 times true for me...

Comment: i think it's bug, i have 262 false /  738 true

Comment: it's something weird with chrome's console: if you push to an array and log the array, it's all `false`. as-is, the number of `true`s fluctuates in chrome.

Comment: @HoàngLong as I said in the question, it happens only on some machines. It is also possible that it happens only on some versions of Chrome

Comment: @HoàngLong make sure you're running it in Chrome

Comment: Firefox and Safari will print 1000 `false`.

Comment: seems like Chrome only thing

Comment: Very interesting. The function seems to be implied someway, issuing `for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) console.log(typeof null === "undefined");` results in 1000 times `false`.

Comment: It starts happening at `i < 264` in my Chrome, I have `Version 51.0.2704.103 m`

Comment: I'm iterating to 100 and getting 100 false in chrome

Comment: How about `var results = []; for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) results.push(foo());
console.log(results);`?

Comment: Looks like it is only happening when using `console.log` to print the result to the console, see https://jsfiddle.net/q6s4w5g9/.

Comment: Isn't this just a reiteration of a bug that has been circulating the internet for a day now? If you didn't discover this, at least link to where you found out about it...

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen yes, it is my understanding this has been making the rounds lately. Since I received that screenshot in a private chat, I can't link to my source.

Comment: @Nobita Makes me glad I use Firefox. =)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is a chromium bug open for this:

[Issue 604033 - JIT compiler not preserving method behavior](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604033)

So yes It's just a bug!

Comment: "Just"? Couldn't this break arbitrary web applications world-wide?

Comment: "Just" only to say that is not a feature or something strange. Is a critical bug, but just a bug!

Answer (score 37):

It's actually a [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) JavaScript engine ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine))) bug.

This engine is used in Chromium, Maxthron, Android OS, Node.js etc.

Relatively simple [bug description](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4oxtgk/javascript_developers_be_warned_about_this_crazy/d4grsr0) you can find in this [Reddit topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4oxtgk/javascript_developers_be_warned_about_this_crazy/):

> Modern JavaScript engines compile JS code into optimized machine code
>   when it is executed (Just In Time compilation) to make it run faster.
>   However, the optimization step has some initial performance cost in
>   exchange for a long term speedup, so the engine dynamically decides
>   whether a method is worth it depending on how commonly it is used.
>
> In this case there appears to be a bug only in the optimized path,
>   while the unoptimized path works fine. So at first the method works as
>   intended, but if it's called in a loop often enough at some point the
>   engine will decide to optimize it and replaces it with the buggy
>   version.

This bug seems to have been fixed in V8 itself ([commit](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/7dfb5beeec8821521beeb2b8eac36707a663064c)), aswell as in Chromium ([bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604033)) and NodeJS ([commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/7348)).

Comment: I confirmed the bug is still in Node.js 6.2.2 which worries me.

Comment: It was fixed in V8 engine today (21.06), I believe soon related software will be updated.

Comment: Backporting the v8 fix to Node.js 6.2.x is already in progress as issue [#7348](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/7348) owned by [TheAlphaNerd](https://github.com/TheAlphaNerd).

Answer (score 18):

To answer the direct question of why it changes, the bug is in the "JIT" optimisation routine of the V8 JS engine used by Chrome. At first, the code is run exactly as written, but the more you run it, the more potential there is for the benefits of optimisation to outweigh the costs of analysis.

In this case, after repeated execution in the loop, the JIT compiler analyses the function, and replaces it with an optimised version. Unfortunately, the analysis makes an incorrect assumption, and the optimised version doesn't actually produce the correct result.

Specifically, [Reddit user RainHappens suggests](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4oxtgk/javascript_developers_be_warned_about_this_crazy/d4grqo1) that it is an error in *type propagation*:

> It also does some type propagation (as in what types a variable etc can be). There's a special "undetectable" type for when a variable is undefined or null. In this case the optimizer goes "null is undetectable, so it can be replaced with the "undefined" string for the comparison.

This is one of the hard problems with optimising code: how to guarantee that code which has been rearranged for performance will still have the same effect as the original.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed two month ago and will land in Chrome soon (already in Canary).

[V8 Issue 1912553002 - Fix 'typeof null' canonicalization in crankshaft](https://codereview.chromium.org/1912553002)

[Chromium Issue 604033 - JIT compiler not preserving method behavior](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604033)