# Is the keyword "let" trustworthy in JS?

Tags: javascript, let

I've never really used `let` in JS yet. But with a few dev in my company we just found out something quite strange. I can't explain it.

When I execute the following code in a browser (tested on Chrome `Version 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit)`)

```
for (let i = 0; i<10000; i++) {
    console.log(typeof null == 'undefined')
} 

4917 false
5083 true
```

If I use `var` instead of `let` then I get `10000 false`, which is what's expected.

I tried to run it several times on several webpages and the result is always the same. It makes me wonder if `let` is correctly integrated within the browsers, because this doesn't seem trustworthy at all and I wonder what kind of other bugs this can produce.

Any insight? The fact that the result is always the same seems to indicate that there is some logic behind it, but I can't grasp it.

Comment: It was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939455/why-does-the-value-of-typeof-null-change-inside-a-loop

Comment: Works fine for me (`52.0.2743.41 beta-m (64-bit)`)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `let`. Yes, it's just a simple bug going viral.

Comment: Very interesting, for me it is  `4099 false` and `5901 true` on Chrome . Then FireFox `4917 false` and `5083 true`...

Comment: I assumed it was related to `let` since the result was correct using `var`.